# Custom UIPageControl dots color not changing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have UIPageControl which I have made custom its dot color is not changing

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if (hidesForSinglePage == NO || [self numberOfPages] > 1){
        if (activePageColor == nil){
            activePageColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }

        if (inactivePageColor == nil){
            inactivePageColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //  float dotSize = self.frame.size.height / 6;
    float dotSize = self.frame.size.height / 2;
    float dotsWidth = (dotSize * [self numberOfPages]) + (([self numberOfPages] - 1) 10);

    float offset = (self.frame.size.width - dotsWidth) / 2;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [self numberOfPages]; i++){
        if (i == [self currentPage]){
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [activePageColor CGColor]);
        } else {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [inactivePageColor CGColor]);
        }

        CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(offset + (dotSize + 10) * i,(self.frame.size.height / 2) - (dotSize / 2), dotSize, dotSize));
    }
}
```

if I change CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect with CGContextFillEllipseInRect then its changing but I want to use CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the fill color, but you want to use a stroke function.  Use `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` instead of `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`.